# filling scores to rows based on column value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this

```
Example1:

score_df
========
rid score Flag
1    5     y
1    6     n
1    7     y
1    8     n
```

i need to copy the scores to the remaining rows when Flag = 'y' appears first. In this example, flag=y appeared on first row when score is 5. i would copy the score 5 to remaining rows. output would look like this.

```
score_df
========
rid score Flag
1    5     y
1    5     n
1    5     y
1    5     n


Example2:

score_df
========
rid score Flag
1    5     n
1    6     y
1    7     n
1    8     y
```

in this case, the flag value is y only on the second row where score is 6. output would look like this

```
score_df
========
rid score Flag
1    5     n
1    6     y
1    6     n
1    6     n
```

So, i would like to fill the rows based on the first occurrence of flag value. How to do this in pandas without looping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask for match all values after first `y` value with compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare gor greater like `0` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and set first match value to only filtered columns values:

```
m = df['Flag'].eq('y').cumsum().gt(0)

df.loc[m, 'score'] = df.loc[m, 'score'].iat[0]
print (df)
   rid  score Flag
0    1      5    y
1    1      5    n
2    1      5    y
3    1      5    n
```

---

```
df.loc[m, 'score'] = df.loc[m, 'score'].iat[0]
print (df)
   rid  score Flag
0    1      5    n
1    1      6    y
2    1      6    y
3    1      6    n
```

Solution if possible no match (no `y` value in column) is a bit different, `next` with `iter` return first value if exist, here it set `0` values by only `False` mask, so no replace.

This solution also working for data above, so is more general.

```
df.loc[m, 'score'] = next(iter(df.loc[m, 'score']), 0)
print (df)
   rid  score Flag
0    1      5    n
1    1      6    n
2    1      7    n
3    1      8    n
```